# SQL To JPQL with UUID

Tags: sql, jpql, uuid

I am trying to use JPQL to retrieve a message using an ID that is of type UUID.

This is the correct SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM C2_MESSAGES WHERE ID = x'a9181d1c429a4b67b1379bc9ee6a68e7';
```

I've tried different variations of this

```
UUID uid = UUID.fromString(c2MessageId);   
String messageQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT msg FROM C2Message msg WHERE msg.id = " + uid;
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Don't concatenate strings. Use prepared statements or Query parameters `Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM message m WHERE m.id = :id"); q.setParameter("id", uid);` this lowers the risk that someone refactories the class and the uid is injected truly as a String (SQL Injection)

Answer (score 1):

Escape string with single quotes `'`:

```
String messageQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT msg FROM C2Message msg WHERE msg.id = '" + uid + "'";
```

Comment: tried same approach, but getting cast exception from jpql. tried to match uuid with 'uuid'. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

In Sql, it is a best practice to escape Strings with single quotes if 
you write your query in double quotes.

This prevents from many erros. 
Try this code, it should work:

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT msg FROM C2Message msg WHERE msg.id ='"+uid+"'";
```